# PHP - Script works on localhost but won't work on server

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

I cant seem to figure out why **some** of my scripts execute perfectly on my WAMP server, but refuse to work on the online testing server I tried running it on today, whereas some of them work perfectly fine. I've chcked the cases and the script doesn't see to be returning any errors (I've removed some of the if statements that i used for echoing errors). *I've searched the net and there are similar problems, but i cant find any with this exact code.* I think there is a sneaky syntax error in here somewhere, but just can not find it!

I am not very experienced with PHP (I mainly do HTML/CSS frontend work and have two months of programming on the clock) and would really appreciate if you guys could help me out. Sorry if this is a noob question, but I sort of am a noob at this :)

The PHP version the online server is running is 5.2.13

```
   <?php

    include ("Connections/LigatureUplink.php");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }


    $somevar = $con->prepare("UPDATE `ligature_tenants` SET  `name` = ?, `image` = ?, `bio` = ? WHERE idLEIETAKERE = ?");
    //var_dump($somevar);
    $theID = $_POST['id'];  
    $theNAME = $_POST['title'];  
    $theIMAGE = $_POST['image'];  
    $theBIO = $_POST['content'];  

    $theNAME = htmlspecialchars($theNAME, ENT_HTML5);
    $theIMAGE = htmlspecialchars($theIMAGE, ENT_HTML5);
    $theBIO = htmlspecialchars($theBIO, ENT_HTML5);
    $theID = htmlspecialchars($theID, ENT_HTML5);
    $theSELECT = "sssi";

    $somevar->bind_param($theSELECT, $theNAME, $theIMAGE, $theBIO, $theID);
    //$somevar->execute();

    if(!$somevar->execute()) echo $somevar->error;

    echo mysqli_errno($con) . ": " . mysqli_error($con) . "\n";

    $somevar->close();

    ?>
```

Here's LigatureUplink.php

```
   <?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQLi"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_LigatureUplink = "HOSTNAME";
$database_LigatureUplink = "DATABASE";
$username_LigatureUplink = "USERNAME";
 $password_LigatureUplink = "PASSWORD";
 $LigatureUplink = mysqli_connect($hostname_LigatureUplink, $username_LigatureUplink,  $password_LigatureUplink, $database_LigatureUplink) or trigger_error(mysqli_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 

$con = $LigatureUplink;
?>
```

Comment: what goes wrong when you run this code?

Comment: Where is it failing? What is the error message? What have you tried to debug the error?

Comment: Since you can't tell us HOW these scripts are failing, we can't really help you. You'll have to make sure that PHP is running with `display_errors` and `error_reporting` enabled. They should never be off while you're debugging/testing, in any case.

Comment: @marc: I don't have access to PHP.ini at the moment, so I'm not quite sure how to enable those two.

Comment: So I'm not quite sure WHAT goes wrong, all i know is it doesn't update the posts for whatever reason. I was hoping there was a very obvious error here that I just was too inexperienced to see.

Comment: You can try putting `ini_set()` calls at the start of your script, and hope that whatever the problem is, it isn't causing a fatal parse error BEFORE those ini_set() calls can actually be executed.